# Creating VIEWS on Microsoft SQL Server for Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, report, view

I'm trying to create a view for my report for 
the Staff Sales.

My Staff Fields are
Staff_ID - PRIMARY KEY
Staff_Name

My Sale Fields are
Sale_Date
Payment_ID@
Staff_ID@
Sale_ID - PRIMARY KEY

I'm trying to calculate how much sales each member of staff has made, How would I go about this? I have tried this but as you can see I'm not very good at views in sql.

```
SELECT tblSale.Staff_ID,
SUM(tblSale.Sale_ID*tblSale.Staff_ID) AS 
SalesPerStaff FROM tblSale

INNER JOIN tblStaff ON tblSale.Sale_ID = tblStaff.Staff_ID
GROUP BY tblSale.Sale_ID
```

Comment: What does "how much sales" mean?  Just a count?

Comment: Yep, I want to be able to tell how many sales each staff member made. e.g. Staff_ID 1 = PRODUCT LIST OF ITEMS SOLD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is just the same as a standard piece of T-SQL, it's just stored in the database ready to be called when you need it

```
CREATE VIEW MyViewName
AS
SELECT
st.Staff_ID
,st.Staff_Name
,COUNT(sa.Sale_ID) Sales
FROM Staff st
LEFT JOIN Sale sa
ON st.Staff_ID = sa.Staff_ID
GROUP BY 
st.Staff_ID
,st.Staff_Name
```

That way, you can just call MyViewName and it will give you results. I've used a LEFT JOIN in case you have staff with no sales.

If your Sales table has a value column, you can change COUNT(Sale_ID) to SUM(Sales_Value) or whatever the field is called.

Just read your reply to main question. If your Sales table has something like 'Item_ID' then just add this after st.Staff_Name in the select list (remember to add to the end of the GROUP BY too).

Comment: You are a genius, Honestly. My uni teacher has took "indefinite" leave and hasn't even bothered to guide our class! Thanks Rich!

Comment: No worries at all, give me a shout if you need any of the logic explaining

Comment: Thanks Rich, Could I please contact you if I need any assistance?

Comment: I'll be honest, I only pop on here on breaks from my day job so I wouldn't be able to respond quickly at times. If you post your questions here I'm sure it would be fine, just make sure that you explain that it's for a class and your professor is on indefinite leave at the moment. Be sure to give good explanations of what you're trying to do and what steps you've already taken. People will help you learn this stuff by pointing you to the correct resources.